# Bootstrap tooltip out of alignment

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, css-animations

I am having some weirdness with Bootstrap tooltip animations.

I have created some breadcrumbs using this demo (example 9) https://codyhouse.co/demo/breadcrumbs-multi-steps-indicator/index.html
 and I've added bootstrap tooltips to each link.  This all works fine.

I added some animations using this stylesheet https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
         $('.tooltip').addClass('animated bounceIn');         
    });
});
```

When i first hover over a link, the tooltip animates as expected however when I hover over the same link again after hovering over another link, the animation and tooltip have moved to the left by quite a few pixels. It only workds properly when the link is first hovered.

[I've created a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9dqz983/1)

Here is a screenshot of what I see when I first hover over a link

[image]

And this is what i see when i revist that same link

[image]

Comment: Something caused by `bounceIn` css class

Comment: Yeah as @Morpheus said, if you remove `bounceIn` from `addClass()` the position looks correct

Comment: I use the bounceIn class for the animation which works on hover

Comment: Interesting...it was the bounceIn class. I tried a different class on it worked as it should

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `bounceIn` class when you mouseOut from the menu item using `hide.bs.tooltip`:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('hide.bs.tooltip', function() {
  $('.tooltip').removeClass('animated bounceIn');
});
```

See it working here - https://jsfiddle.net/n9dqz983/4/